# Selected_visible_fcurves from the 3D Viewport?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the [selected visible keyframes](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.selected_visible_fcurves) in a Graph Editor from a 3D Viewport. If I try `context.selected_visible_fcurves` in the 3D Viewport, it returns `None`, but in the Graph Editor it works. How may I switch context from my operator in the 3D Viewport?

I'm currently doing this:

```py
previous_area_type = context.area.type
context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'
fcurves = context.selected_visible_fcurves
context.area.type = previous_area_type
```

Is there a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it like this:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context


for window in context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        print(area.type)
        if area.type == 'GRAPH_EDITOR':
            with context.temp_override(window=window, area=area):
                print (context.selected_visible_fcurves)
            break
```

more info:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context

Comment: That was what I needed. Thank you, Chris!

Comment: you are welcome